# Laptop can't enter BIOS but boots fine

Tags: boot, bios, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo T430. It boots into Arch Linux without issue but when I try to enter BIOS configuration or the menu to choose a boot device, it hangs with a blank screen.

Things I have tried:

- Updating the BIOS
- Removing the hard drive and mSATA SSD
- Disconnecting the backup battery (clock was reset when I booted, so it did take)
- Booting while connected to external monitors to see if it was set to display onto them instead of the builtin display

It's currently set up to boot UEFI only (or possibly UEFI/Legacy) with SecureBoot disabled.

I don't know what the issue is. Any knowledge would be helpful.

Comment: this doesn't look that great but it may help https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/Unable-to-enter-into-BIOS-T430s-2353/td-p/850895

Comment: @barlop Thanks, but I've already tried clearing the CMOS

Comment: I wouldn't think this is that likely to work but if you're on windows 8, one poster in that thread suggests some mumbo jumbo with a windows 8 option that might help

Comment: There is a thread on this at Lenovo forums, https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/Cannot-get-into-BIOS-using-F1-or-Enter/td-p/799001 . One suggestion is to update BIOS. Another cause of the issue is that boot occurs so fast that the key must be held down *before* restarting, or BIOS setup is bypassed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved it. I cleared some old crash logs from the EFI variable storage and updated my bootloader (was using Gummiboot, which has been replaced by systemd boot).

I believe the part that did it was updating the bootloader, but I can't be sure since I did them both so close together. When the bootloader was updated, it cleared away all the boot menu items that the bootloader had been tracking all this time, which may have had something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is comon problem in all lenovo laptops. I also have faced this problem so many times. For solving this please goto link i provided (link of oficial lenovo support site) and download latest bios setup and install it it will updte your bios and all will be all right.
download bios setfor window 8.1 and install it the manual also given in pdf format.
if you already have latest bios installed in your laptop than even lenovo customer care can't help you because they may know that type of problems or may not have proper solution. but try 99% it will work for you

http://support.lenovo.com/in/hi/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t430

Answer (score -1):

On my T430s I couldn't get into BIOS.  I tried all sorts of combinations of keys.  Each time I shut the computer down and then powered on and tried another key or keys.  Then I tried just reboot from Windows.  As soon as the screen went blank, I started pushing F1 and letting it up, in quick succession.  It went to BIOS.
Thinker